# Pushwoosh onDeviceReady with timezone offset

Tags: cordova, pushwoosh

We're working on hybrid apps using cordova and registering our ios devices for push-notifications using [pushwoosh](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin) plugin.

However we cannot pass any config using the `registerDevice()` method as it only accepts success and error callback. So we pass everything on the 'onDeviceReady()' function. As per the docs for pushwoosh [registerDevice](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/) we can pass in the `timezone` parameter to specify the UTC offset. However I can't find the similar way when using the pushwoosh cordova plugin.

I can't find any docs that specifies me the list of variables I can pass in the `onDeviceReady()` function. I've referred [this blog](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/) and it only shows that we can pass in the `pw_appid`.

Is there any resource where I can find the details for using the pushwoosh cordova plugin and passing in the timezone while registering the device or on device ready?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass timezone, SDK detects timezone from device settings automatically.